# How can I get data about Wikipedians (e.g. language proficiency), by username?

Tags: wikidata, wikipedia

Is there an open dataset containing information such as username, language proficiency levels (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Babel/Levels) and (possibly) academic degrees and nationality of Wikipedians? This info is (often) displayed in Users' pages https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:usernamepages in the form of badges. I am not looking for aggregates, but for granular username-level data.

I couldn't find data of this kind at https://dumps.wikimedia.org/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create your own, either by scraping the HTML or parsing down the full export/dump.

First, get a list of lists

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Wikipedians_by_degree
```

Then, loop through each list

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Wikipedians_with_PhD_degrees
```

And collect the usernames per degree.

If you need more data, for example degree AND region, then it's easy enough to parse the HTML, and identify the relevant `userbox`, although be careful for users with multiple degrees/nationalities.

```
<div class="wikipediauserbox" style="float:left;border:1px solid #808080;margin:1px;width:238px">
   <table role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:238px;margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;background:#FFEEEE">
      <tr>
         <td style="border:0;width:45px;height:45px;background:#FF8888;text-align:center;font-size:14pt;font-weight:bold;color:black;padding:0 1px 0 0;line-height:1.25em;vertical-align:middle">PhD</td>
         <td style="border:0;text-align:left;font-size:8pt;padding:0 4px 0 4px;height:45px;line-height:1.25em;color:black;vertical-align:middle">This user has a <a href="/wiki/Doctor_of_Philosophy" title="Doctor of Philosophy">Doctor of Philosophy</a> degree.</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

You can make it even easier and just say that a userpage that, for example, links to `/wiki/Doctor_of_Philosophy` has a PhD.

You'll also have to pick a language page (`en` for example), since userpages are also language specific.